# Creating conditional tasks based on certain tags

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a conditional task based on the selection of a previous tag.

For instance, if the Tag "team meeting" is chosen, on a task, I would want another column (for example "status description") to have to be filled out.

Not sure if this is possible on SharePoint and would be great to get some certainty if it does.

Comment: Hi, does my below answer help you in any way? Let me know if you need any further help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show/hide list form fields in SharePoint using conditional formulas based on the values of another fields on the list form.

**Example**:

Show/hide "Status Description" column based on the Category column in the list. Below example will show "Status Description" column only when "Team Meeting" option is selected in the Category column.

```
=if([$Category] == 'Team Meeting', 'true', 'false')
```

Where `Category` is the internal name of your list column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Follow below documentation for detailed steps and more examples related to this topic:

**Microsoft documentation**: [Specify conditional formula to show or hide columns in the SharePoint list form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#specify-conditional-formula-to-show-or-hide-columns)